# looking for 'Search & Download' extension for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, search, downloadable, media

Is there any extension available for Magento 2 that offers the ability to search for a SKU/ProductName and return result download links for related files ( such as driver firmware, user manual,etc)... something like this https://downloadcenter.intel.com/
I could only find product attachments extensions, which add a tab to the product page.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the downloadable links paid or you want them allowed to download at without any charge?

Comment: without any charges. it mainly gonna be for firmware updates and pdf manuals

Comment: might be [Magento 2 Quick Order](https://www.mageants.com/wholesale-fast-order-for-magento-2.html) extension will help to resolve your issues

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Quick Order will help you out to achieve your requirement. However, check the features list and demo if it is helpful for you:

https://www.magedelight.com/magento-2-extensions/quick-order-magento-2.html

Comment: in order to use this one, seems like i'll need to create each file as an "downloadable products"?

Comment: Right! you have to create each file as a downloadable product. It will depend if you want them chargeable or not :)